# How to extract JS and CSS from Vue single file to *.js and *.css

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-loader

Suppose I have wrote a omponent `a.vue`,After packaging of webpack,some HTML that has used `a.vue` looks like this:

```html
......
<script src="page.js"></script>
<link href="page.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
......
```

JS and CSS in `a.Vue` are packed into `page.js` and `page.css`.I want to know how to extract JS and CSS into separate files.Then HTML looks like:

```html
<script src="a.js"></script>
<script src="page.js"></script>
<link href="a.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="page.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

I know it's not good to do this, I just want to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simmilar question on github. Maybe you can try the given solution

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/681

```
configure webpack.prod.conf.js
config.entry = {}
config.entry[one.name] = one.path
config.output.libraryTarget = 'umd'
config.output.library = `${namespace}${one.importName}`
config.output.filename = `index.min.js`
config.output.path = path.resolve(__dirname, `../dist/components/${one.name}/`)
```

built it with

```
webpack(config, function (err, stats) {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I LOVE Single File Components (SFC) but it's really easy to separate html, css and js with Vue.

**MyComponent.vue**

```
<template>
  // html
</template>

<script src="./MyComponent.js"></script>
<style scoped src="./MyComponent.css">
</style>
```

[See a simple example on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/separate-vue-component-into-html-css-js-f0n4c?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

Comment: Thanks,But I've tried it like this. It doesn't work. Can you send the webpack configuration

Answer (score 0):

Use `vue-cli` create project then it can auto extract css and js.

I'm checking its webpack configuration